# forms component of react-native-elements cause "Invariant Violation" error

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am using the sample instructed [here](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/forms.html)
But it throws `Invariant Violation: element Type is invalid: expected a string`
error page.

Button component works fine but somehow Forms component cause this issue,

Anyone used forms component of react-native-elements before and know how to fix it?

Here code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { Input, Button, FormLabel, FormInput, FormValidationMessage } from 'react-native-elements';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  Login = ()=>{
  }
  onChangeText=()=>{
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <Text> Login Page </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
  large
  icon={{name: 'key', type: 'octicon', buttonStyle: styles.someButtonStyle }}
  title='Oturum Aç' onPress={()=>this.Login()} />
      </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of react-native-elements are you using? I have seen this error before, and it was related to using a Component which was not supported by the installed version of react-native-elements.

I see you are importing both Input and FormLabel, but I believe Input is only supported in the v1.0.0 beta version while FormLabel isn't supported anymore on v1.0.0 beta.

Comment: Yeah u right Input works, since my using 1.0.0-beta7. Then I should remove and continue with Input components only